# How to access data in a nested array in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The answer to this question seems obvious but a struggle to fin the solution.

My data structure:

[image: Data structure]

I try to access the url of the first image of a property object.

```
 <tr v-for="property in properties">
        <th scope="row">${property.id}</th>
        <td><a :href="'#'">${property.title} - ${property.images[0].image}</a>
        </td>
```

Unfortunately `property.images[0].image` doesn't work.

I'm new to Vue.js. Maybe I don't see something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems as correct as it could be. Did you change delimiters because of this page is also rendering on server side?. Only guess I have is that your provided data comes to frontend after page is rendered, and you trying to achieve it not from vue instance so it is not wrapped with vue's setters and getters, so the reactivity breaks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just found a solution - see below. I changed delimiters because it's a Django project and Django templates use curly braces as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know what are you trying to achieve but here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    properties: [{
        id: 0,
        title: 'foo',
        images: [{
            image: 'foo image 1'
          },
          {
            image: 'foo image 2'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'bar',
        images: [{
            image: 'bar 1'
          },
          {
            image: 'bar 1'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(property, index) in properties" :key="index">
        <td scope="row">{{property.id}}</td>
        <td><a :href="'#'">{{property.title}} - {{property.images[0].image}}</a>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Also use [`:key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) attribute when using `v-for`.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but you can change the delimiters in Vue.js and I changed theme to use ${} instead of curly braces => https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#delimiters - So you doesn't really answer my question. BTW :key is not mandatory. So you down voted my question without any reason.

Comment: Firstly, didn't know about the `delimiters` option so thanks for sharing some new input. Secondly, I didn't downvoted your question - but on the contrary, I took some time to answer it with a working example. As I stated, your question is unclear, but I provided you with a working snippet. Thirdly - it's good practice to add the `:key` attribute.

Comment: When I said thank you I really meant it, because you took time. No offense :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer! it's silly :)

Some property objects doesn't have images.

So when I put property.images[0].image it doesn't exist. It seems that vue.js doesn't render the whole content if an attribute you try to reach doesn't exist (I'm not sure about that, just guessing).

Here is the code that makes it work:

```
<tr v-for="property in properties">
    <th scope="row">${property.id}</th>
    <td v-if="property.images[0]"><a :href="'#'">${property.title} - ${property.images[0].image}</a>
    </td>
```

First I check if the attribute exists with the following code :

`v-if="property.images[0]"`